# MDX SORTING not Working

Tags: mdx, pentaho

I want to sort one column in the desending format.The MDX query need to sort out is shown below.In der I am using the "[Measures].[Count]" field in the where clause.And i want to sort the measures in descending format..I already used the "ORDER" Function in the qry.bt i am getting errors..

/*

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Operator].[Total],[Operator].[Total] .Children } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { [Circle].[Total], [Circle].[Total] .Children } ON ROWS FROM 
[GENERATOR] 
WHERE 
( [Measures].[Count], [RoamingFlag].[INRoaming], [Date].[${yesterday}] ,           [SuccessFailureDetails].[FAILURE] )

*/
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem..
        Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT

NON EMPTY {[Operator].[Total],[Operator].[Total].Children} ON COLUMNS,

NON EMPTY ORDER({[Circle].[Total],[Circle].[Total].Children},[Measures].[Count],BASC) ON ROWS FROM [GENERATOR]

WHERE 
([Measures].[Count], [RoamingFlag].[INRoaming], [Date].[${yesterday}],[SuccessFailureDetails].[FAILURE])`

Hopefully!